# Можно ли делать concat, а потом очищать массив?

Tags: node.js

1. `let a = [].concat(b);`
2. `b = [];`

Мне нужно сделать из массива B копию в массиве A, и очистить массив B.

Гарантируется ли, что после строки 1 сразу будет исполнена строка 2?

А то вдруг исполнение перейдет к участку кода, где в массив B будут добавлены данные и затем он будет очищен, но массив A не будет иметь этот элемент.

Comment: если используется обычный массив - то да

Comment: Оффтоп, `a = b.slice()` — быстрее и не создаёт лишний пустой массив.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При использовании обычных массивов, невозможно изменить значение *между* двух последовательных строчек. Так как исполнение происходит в главном потоке.

Поэтому, если в коде примера между строкой 1 и строкой 2 нет других строк, они будут выполнены строго последовательно.